# Read data & use as axis labels

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have my data in a CSV file with different columns. One column contains data from a temperature measurement, the other the respective timestamps. I would like to plot the data and add timestamps on the x-axis. Since I have 839 time stamps, I would only like to plot a time stamp every 4 hours.

What I have is the plot and the axis ticks in the right positions. However, I have problems reading the time labels in a way it allows me using them as tick labels.

```
time <- Ankle.r[,2]
time2 <- time[seq(1, length(time), 48)]       #4h*12samplings/h -> 48
time3 <- data.frame(lapply(time2, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now I have all the time stamps I need in one row.

The first problem: I would not like to plot the seconds, but reduce the `%H:%M:%S` format to `%H:%M`.

Second problem: I need the data so I can use them as labels for x-axis ticks (here `labels = c(time3)`) in my `geom_line` plot.

```
p <- ggplot(data=Tempdata, 
        aes(x = MSZP, 
            y = Tempdata, colour = "Temperature Differences")) 
p + geom_line(aes(x=MSZP, y = Tempdata$Proximal.vs.Ankles, colour = "Prox vs. Ankles")) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(), name = "Temperature Differences")+
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(1,839*5,240)), 
                   labels = c(time3), name = "Messzeitpunkt")
```

Comment: Can you share a sample subset of the data? It'd be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I am just trying, but it's not so easy...is there a way of uploading files here?

Comment: (a) pls put output of at least `dput(head(Tempdata, 15))` into the question; (b) you can use the `scale_x_datetime` function vs `scale_x_continuous` and that has the ability to format the labels.

Comment: It is working now! I have no idea why, but I just added this to my code:
`code`theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0.5))+
Maybe there was just not enough space before, wherefore tick labels could not be plotted?